# List difference with list constructed by Arrays.asList has surprising result. Why?

Tags: java, java-collections-api

What value for "zs" do you expect after the following snippet has run?

```
Collection<Integer> xs = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
int[] ys = {1};
List<Integer> zs = new ArrayList<>(xs);
zs.removeAll(Arrays.asList(ys));
```

I would have expected a list containing 2 and 3. However, with JDK 1.8.0_25 in Eclipse 4.5 M7 it is a list containing 1, 2, 3. The removal has no effect. However, when I specify "ys" as a non-primitive array, I get the expected result:

```
Collection<Integer> xs = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
Integer[] ys = {1};
List<Integer> zs = new ArrayList<>(xs);
zs.removeAll(Arrays.asList(ys));
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure that `Arrays.asList(ys)` has the type you think it does? (I think it is `List<int[]>`)

Comment: The moral of the story is: varargs, generics and arrays of primitives don't play well together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `Arrays.asList(int[])` is `List<int[]>`. As such, none of the elements in `xs` is contained in that list.